# How to package bibliographies into their own package in LaTeX3

Tags: bibliographies, packages, latex3

I would like to put my references into a single package to use across documents. Right now I have a `.bib` file with the listings, and import it into a `.cls` file as `\bibliography{./my/local/bibliography}`.

I would like to instead just do this, either:

```
\usepackage{mybibliography}
...
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

Or simply just:

```
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

(without the need for `\usepackage`). Not sure if that is possible or necessary.

How to go about accomplishing this. Not sure what needs to be published or compiled into a package given that it's just a `.bib` file essentially. All I have so far is:

```
%
% Set latex version.
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018/03/16 MyBibliography]

%
% Import packages.
%
% I would like to do this in a separate document class rather than here.
%

\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}

%
% Style bibliography.
%
% I would like to do this in a separate document class rather than here.
%

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

%
% ...where to include the .bib file / what to do with that.
%
```